I am encountering an error related to static file serving in Quarkus after uploading a new file until I restart Quarkus server
I am using the template provided in Quarkus documentation for the static file serving, and my mp3 save fn.
package com.example.songcomponent.song.repository;

import io.quarkus.runtime.StartupEvent;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;
import jakarta.enterprise.event.Observes;


public class StaticResources {

    void installRoute(@Observes StartupEvent startupEvent, Router router) {
        router.route()
            .path("/static/*")
            .handler(StaticHandler.create("static/"));
    }
}


public Response saveSong(InputStream fileInputStream) {
    String UPLOAD_DIRECTORY = "/Users/a/Desktop/x/x/src/main/resources/static/";
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY));
        String fileName = "audio_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".mp3";
        File uploadedFile = new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + fileName);
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(uploadedFile)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Response.created(UriBuilder.fromPath(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY).build()).build();
}


@POST
    @Path("/savesong")
    @PermitAll
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response savesong(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream 
fileInputStream) {
        return songService.saveSong(fileInputStream);
    }

Getting an error until I am restarting a server:
2024-04-03 19:33:51,462 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor] (vert.x-worker-thread-1) Files changed but restart not needed - notified extensions in: 0.075s uarkusDev
2024-04-03 19:33:51,618 ERROR [io.qua.ver.htt.run.QuarkusErrorHandler] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-1) HTTP Request to /static/audio_1712169223992.mp3 failed, error id: 9d613d1f-f728-46f4-8977-1161222efa2d-3: io.vertx.core.VertxException: Invalid resource: static/audio_1712169223992.mp3
at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileResolverImpl.unpackFromFileURL(FileResolverImpl.java:278)
at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileResolverImpl.unpackUrlResource(FileResolverImpl.java:246)
at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileResolverImpl.resolveFile(FileResolverImpl.java:171)
at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.resolveFile(VertxImpl.java:929)
at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileSystemImpl$20.perform(FileSystemImpl.java:1135)
at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileSystemImpl$20.perform(FileSystemImpl.java:1133)
at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileSystemImpl$BlockingAction.handle(FileSystemImpl.java:1174)
at io.vertx.core.file.impl.FileSystemImpl$BlockingAction.handle(FileSystemImpl.java:1156)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:190)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:276)
at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$internalExecuteBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:209)
at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2513)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1538)
at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)

Do you have a sample application we can try?

https://github.com/arturs706/quarkus_cp

Using that how would one reproduce the problem?
